# twitter status code?

Tags: html, twitter, status

I'm trying to make a link to update twitter status with a link..but it keeps saying invalid unicode? I've also tried using the html tag for the pound sign but it fails, any suggestions?

```
<a href="http://twitter.com/home?status=Check out this website #name at http://www.google.com">
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to [encode the status](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Url_encoding) to put it into a URL. To do this, you can do so manually, [use online tools](http://jlpoutre.home.xs4all.nl/BoT/Javascript/Utils/endecode.html) or do it [via code](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php).